# Should Objects get their own Z-index?

Tags: html, web

So I am converting some old code, and in it I have found each Textbox, label and Dropdown was given its own unique Z-Index.  Now, I thought this was pretty pointess (we were not hiding any objects, which is usually when I use Z-Indexes) but when I was talking with a coworker, they said everything should have its own Z-Index (to meet HTML standards).

I tried Googling, but most of the links I found were just about overlapping.  Is this an HTML standard?  Have I been missing this standard for the last 10 years and just lucked out enough to never be annoyed by it?

Thanks

Comment: No, each element does not need its own z-index.

Comment: Consider reading an article about z-index.

Comment: What browsers are you supporting?

Comment: @Strixy:  99.99% IE (almost everything is internal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing legacy support for IE 7 and lower and you have any relative or absolutely positioned elements in the page then the z-indexes may be necessary as IE 6 and 7 especially have difficulties calculating layered objects (note: nothing to do with the display property). IE6 has issues especially with absolutely positioned input fields. Check the positioning, if it's absolute or relatively positioned then yes. It sounds like legacy CSS from a while back and someone tried to do with div's what probably should have been done with a table (back then). I'm not familiar with any general best practices concerning applying z-indexes to every element, but I do recall an old form builder in Dreamweaver from a while back that did that.

Answer (score 1):

Z-indices do not **need** to be specified. They're part of CSS, not HTML, anyway.